# Is there a way to register an interface at runtime through the ServiceLocator?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm-light, service-locator

I just read Laurent's Messenger article in MSDN Magazine, tried a couple of tests and everything worked as expected.

In the "Implementing a DialogService" section, I noticed that registration of the IDialogService is done directly with a call to SimpleIoc. Is there anyway to register interfaces calling the ServiceLocator instead?

I thought the whole point of using a ServiceLocator is so you can swap out SimpleIoc with another IOC? If my view and viewmodel call SimpleIoc directly it kind of defeats the purpose. Maybe I'm not understanding how to get the Ioc from the ServiceLocator.

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.IServiceLocator is designed for "Get" scenarios only.

This is because every IoC container has different features, and therefore various ways to perform registrations:

- in code (as you are probably looking for)
- from an XML configuration file
- via some external data source specific to the application

For example, just as it is used in [MVVM Light](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991965.aspx), it can also be used in a very different application: [SharePoint](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648088.aspx)!